# Elastic Search URI Search Filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `movies` ES index with the following mapping:

```
{
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
       "director": {
          "type": "text"
       },
       "genres": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "false"
       },
       "title": {
          "type": "text"
       },
       "year": {
          "type": "long"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

For genres, I'll be submitting an array of strings. Now, I want to allow my customers to submit a query against my endpoint, where I'd proxy `q` request parameter down to ES client.

But I am struggling to filter the data with the URI search the same way it can be achieved by submitting a query as a payload against my index. For instance:

```
GET movies/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { 
              "term": {
                "genres": "War"
              }
            }
          ],

          "must": [
            { 
              "term": {
                "genres": "Foo"
              }
            }
          ],

          "must": [
            { 
              "term": {
                "genres": "Bar"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can the same be achieved via URI search? If so, how?

Comment: Why do you want to use the URI search?. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Frankly, submitting payload on Get is not very Rest-y and if there’s a way to avoid it, I’d go that route

Comment: Also, we are building a task-based UI, where UI will be placing requests against our API backed by ES backend. Therefore, for frontend engineers it will be too much of an effort to build a query like that. And I wouldn’t like to expose a lot of ES intricacies

Comment: You can build a DSL query in backend based upon client request. URI search doesn't support all the features of DSL query.

Comment: It is a good point. But I would like someone to confirm it is the only way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ES documentation

> You can use query parameters to define your search criteria directly
>   in the request URI, rather than in the request body. Request URI
>   searches do not support the full Elasticsearch Query DSL, but are
>   handy for testing.

Based on our discussion, I suggest you build a DSL query in the backend after receiving request from the client. You need to expose an API which will send UI inputs to the backend in a structured format(JSON) which can help you build the DSL query easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it, without the `q` parameter. Version 6.0.1:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/movies/_mapping/doc
{
  "doc": {
    "properties": {
       "director": {
          "type": "text"
       },
       "title": {
          "type": "text"
       },
       "year": {
          "type": "long"
       },
        "genres": {
          "type": "keyword"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Create documents:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/movies/doc/
{
    "title": "title 1",
    "director": "Igor M",
    "year": 2011,
    "genres": ["Bar", "Foo"]
}
```

Query for documents:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/movies/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must":[
       { "match": { "genres": "War" }},
       { "match": { "genres": "Bar" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```